# Implementing multiple interfaces in php

Tags: php, oop, interface

Im currently designing my system in php and have a lot of entities that share common attributes now i was thinking that i could make interfaces in order to abstract things out. I have for example the following entities:

```
Category(name, parent, modification_date, creation_date, state, lang, en_id, sort_order)

Page(name, content, modification_date, creation_date, state, state_message, approver, lang, en_id, seo_description, seo_title)

Faq(name, content, modification_date, creation_date, state, state_message, approver, lang, en_id, seo_description, seo_title)
```

state can either be approved, pending or draft

I was thinking to make the following interfaces in php

```
IAutostoreDate(creation_date, modification_date)
ISeoAble(seo_description, seo_title)
IApprovable(state, state_message, approver)
ITranslatable(lang, en_id)
```

And there are more thing that i would abstract out.

The question is this an advised or discouraged approach since some entity would implement many classes?

Comment: Have you considered using traits (also known as mixins)? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Do you mean for example instead of ISeoAble and IApprovable a common interface? If that is the case sometimes they have to be used one without the other

Comment: Ok i don't think traits would work because instead of applying some logic on a class base i want to apply it on interface base so for example i want to have a function like approve(IApprovable $toApprove)

Comment: This is what interfaces are for. I think that you're doing it right way. You can implement multiple interfaces (while you can't extend multiple classes in PHP), so there's nothing bad in your approach.

Comment: @user1169526 from your comment I'm not sure if you understand the concept of mixins/traits. Common functionality like you're describing seems like the ideal case for mixins.

Comment: I think you arent refering to Interfaces. An interfaces specifies the methods a class has to expose. It does not define in any ways how it's data structure or properties look like. If you want to reuse common attribute groups in your final classes, you have to extend a class and not use it's interface. Since you can't extend multiple classes (one class for each property group) you either have to use traits or cascade your extensions. Anways, you might want to reread the sections on Interfaces and Extensions.

Comment: I am refering to interfaces the data should be abstract and the classes that implement it should implement some methods with their own logic furthermore this is the reason why traits would not be in their place because later if i want to use another entity don't want to change for example the function approve(IApprovable $toApprove) <- this function will not be in the same entity. Also sorry for my bad english. I also understand that i cannot put variables in it but i can place methods that indicate those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Interface contains only the function definition not the function declaration. So you can use a single Interface for common methods.